# Swift How to move indexpath.item next index cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to put all my photo albums in index 0 in the UICollectionViewCell and after another user album (index from 1) in the index cell, but I don't know how to do that. Below is the code I wrote. Please help me.

```
extension CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    userCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections( with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)
    
    let numOfItem = userCollections.count
    return numOfItem + 1
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}

    var coverAsset: PHAsset?
    let collection = userCollections[indexPath.row]
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        fetchReuslt = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        coverAsset = fetchReuslt.firstObject

        if let asset = coverAsset {
            imgManger.requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: CGSize(width: cell.bounds.width , height: cell.bounds.height - 100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { img, _ in
                cell.collectionListCoverImg.image = img
            })
        }
        cell.update(title: "All Photos", count: fetchReuslt.count)

    } else   {
        let fetchedAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: fetchOptions)
        coverAsset = fetchedAssets.firstObject
        if let asset = coverAsset {
            imgManger.requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: CGSize(width: cell.bounds.width , height: cell.bounds.height - 50), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { img, _ in
                cell.collectionListCoverImg.image = img
            })
        }

        cell.update(title: collection.localizedTitle, count: fetchedAssets.count)
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? What do you mean "I want to put all my photo albums in index 0 in the CollectionView cell"?

Comment: this is error meassage Thread 1: "0x6000039f2200: index (3) beyond bounds (3)"

Comment: you shouldn't return  `numOfItem + 1`, it will always be out of index.

Comment: I would like to create a folder containing all the asset files named AllAlbum. I want to place it in the place where the index value of the cell is 0, but if I write the same code as above, It is access the album corresponding to the index value 0 of userCollecition. userCollectionAlum count is 3. So I return numOfItem + 1.  How can I fix it?